# Sworn statement traveling to France

Tags: france

The current travel instructions for going to France require a sworn statement about coronavirus. Does this statement need to be printed as a hard copy, or can it be filled in and signed digitally?

I've searched high and low on the website ans couldn't find anything.

Comment: Where are you travelling from, and what is your vaccination status? I believe that at this time, the sworn statement is only needed for people arriving from orange countries who are not fully vaccinated.

Comment: @jcaron I'm fully vaccinated coming from the UK (orange), and it is still required according to the official website.

Comment: I travelled from UK to France on 12th Feb. The sworn statement was required by the airline (Ryanair) at checkin, but was not checked by French Immigration on arrival - the covid vaccination and test were checked though.

Comment: @Peregrine in my experience requirements of this sort are often left to the airlines for arriving air passengers (including yellow fever vaccination records in pre-COVID times).  Border authorities know that they can trust the airlines to enforce them because the fines for failing to do so are substantial.  The situation for those arriving by other modes of transportation may be different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not designed to be digital and you need to sign it the old fashioned way. On the other hand, it doesn't need to be printed *per se*, you could just copy it by hand. I know that's not necessarily the answer you were expecting but if you are in a bind, haven't prepared it or don't have access to a printer, that's a possibility. That would still be a sworn statement.

It's also hardly being checked.

Comment: Thanks! Great to know. I don't have a printer and getting it printed out is a hassle, so I'll copy it out by hand.